# Order of the values in the streamlit line chart is upside down

Tags: python, charts, streamlit

I am getting data from SQL database and it is converted in to the pandas dataframe. When I try to "print" my chart in streamlit, the order of the values is upside down.

```
dashboard_chart1 = st.line_chart(df, x="time", width=300, height=500)
```

[image]

I was trying to find something in the official streamlit docs, but there is no argument for the order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found a solution!

I was getting data from database with pandas function `pd.read_sql()`. All columns in dataframe were objects. I used function `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(float)` to convert them to floats. Now, my data are shown correctly.

Screenshot from working chart:

[image: screenshot from working chart]